# ORA-01745 error while executing parameterized queries in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm doing something like

```
...
OracleCommand oCommand = new OracleCommand();
oConnection.Open();
oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE user = :User";
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Name", "Employee1");

DbDataReader dbRdr = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

then this throws an exception:

> ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

EDIT: connection string looks like this:

```
"Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_id;Password=pwd;Unicode=True"
```

No error after the `oConnection.Open();` so I assume my connection string is correct.

On which part did I make a mistake?

Comment: Connection string seems wrong (indicated hostname might be incorrect). Could you put it in the question?

Comment: This code seems ok. What is your connection string?

Comment: @Bahamut, is this your real query ? because it shouldn't raise exception on this query

Comment: @Habib My query is pretty much the same. I'm using a simple wrapper but I've put breakpoints and the Parameters and ConnectionText and they're exactly the same as this query.

Comment: @Bahamut, the error indicates usage of reserve word, thats why I asked.

Comment: @Habib Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try renaming the variable to make sure.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> **ORA-01745**: invalid host/bind variable name
>
> **Cause**: A colon in a bind variable or INTO specification was followed by an
> inappropriate name, perhaps a reserved word.
>
> **Action**:   Change the variable name and retry the operation.

from [here](http://ora-01745.ora-code.com/)

To check what are reserved words, click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)

Comment: I was using ':User' as variable name. Gotta tread the Oracle queries carefully... I should try this first next time.

Comment: I cannot help not adding a comment about utterly useless Oracle error messages... Would it hurt too much to include the cause sentence in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap around an oracle connection `using` block and supply the correct connectionString.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    OracleCommand oCommand = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
    ....
}
```