# Trying to insert data into database with sqldatasource, I get this error: ora-01745 invalid host exception, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

I have this code in my aspx file:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="RegisterUserSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>"
        InsertCommand="insert into users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email, gender, birthdate, nationality, currentcity) 
        values (:firstname, :lastname, :username, :password, :email, :gender, :date, :nationality, :currentcity)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="password" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="Char" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="nationality" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="currentcity" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then this is the code behind:

```
 RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["firstname"].DefaultValue = SavedFirstnameBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["lastname"].DefaultValue = SavedLastnameBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["username"].DefaultValue = SavedUsernameBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["password"].DefaultValue = SavedPasswordBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["email"].DefaultValue = SavedEmailBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["gender"].DefaultValue = SavedGenderBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["date"].DefaultValue = BirthdateBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["nationality"].DefaultValue = SavedNationalityBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.InsertParameters["currentcity"].DefaultValue = SavedCurrentCityBox.Text;
                        RegisterUserSQL.Insert();
```

It stops at the last insert() statement and gives the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I never worked with Oracle DB, but short search lead me to [ORA-01745 error while executing parameterized queries in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104218/ora-01745-error-while-executing-parameterized-queries-in-c-sharp), that had a link to [Oracle Reserved Words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), that had a table, that listed `PASSWORD` as a reserved word. Hope that [How do I escape a reserved word in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle) will be of use.

Comment: the reserved word was 'date', but thanks for the hint!