# NLog is not logging on Oracle database, Please how can I get it right

Tags: oracle, nlog, nlog.config

I want to log into Oracle database table using NLog but nothing gets logged. Below is NLog.config file am using. Please what am I doing wrongly?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"    
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="Logtxt.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="false" useTransactions="true"
        dbProvider="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection,System.Data.OracleClient, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        connectionString="Data Source=#####;User ID=######;password=******;Integrated Security=no;"
        commandText="insert into DBO_ERRORLOGS(LOGID,LEVEL,CALLSITE,TYPE,MESSAGE,STACKTRACE,INNEREXCEPTION,ADDITINALINFO,LOGGEDONDATE,USERNAME) values('',:LEVEL,:CALLSITE,:TYPE,:MESSAGE,:STACKTRACE,:INNEREXCEPTION,:ADDITIONALINFO,:DATE,:USERNAME)">
        <parameter name="LEVEL" layout="${Level}" />
        <parameter name="CALLSITE" layout="${Callsite}" />
        <parameter name="DATE" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="TYPE" layout="${exception:format=Type}" />
        <parameter name="MESSAGE" layout="${exception:format=Message}" />
        <parameter name="STACKTRACE" layout="${exception:format=StackTrace}" />
        <parameter name="INNEREXCEPTION" layout="${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}" />
        <parameter name="ADDITIONALINFO" layout="${Message}" />
        <parameter name="USERNAME" layout="${identity}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Just an observation, but it probably isn't a good idea to post your actual username and password on the public Internet. Also, are you getting any kind of error? This sounds more like an NLog issue than anything else.

Comment: The credentials have been removed. Thanks

Comment: Here is the error am getting in the log "Error Database Target[database]: Error initializing target Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Sounds like it isn't finding Logtxt.txt, which is the only file I see specified anywhere in your code.

Comment: I believe its seeing the file because it logs error messages into it

Comment: I have installed the missing package System.Data.OracleClient and now I get a new error "System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name"

Answer (score 0):

Without an error message (see below how to find it), it's a bit guessing. But I think it's an issue you are sending all the parameters as strings. So add the dbType to the parameters, like:

```xml
<parameter name="DATE" layout="${date}" dbType="DateTime" />
```

For the actual error, you should check the internal log. It should be there!
Check `Logtxt.txt`. See `internalLogFile="Logtxt.txt"`. And you can't find it, change it to an absolute path, e.g. `internalLogFile="C:\temp\Logtxt.txt"`

Comment: Here is the error am getting in the log "Error Database Target[database]: Error initializing target Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: I have installed the missing package System.Data.OracleClient and now I get a new error "System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104218/ora-01745-error-while-executing-parameterized-queries-in-c-sharp